# Getting Syslog to log to both syslog and custom log file

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog, syslog, raspbian

In syslog (Raspbian rsyslog swVersion="8.1901.0"),

I am trying to match / filter a system msg containing a specific string BOTH to `/var/log/syslog` (default) AND to a custom separate log file, i.e.: `/var/log/nut.log`.

I have been able to achieve the by placing the following filter lines in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
# NUT logging: Include USB msgs since montoring UPS via only USB
:msg,contains,"USB" /var/log/nut.log
& stop
:msg,contains,"nut-" /var/log/nut.log
& stop
```

The `& stop` is needed to halt the filters once a match is made. I believe the preferred method is to place this in a dedicated file, i.e.: `/etc/rsyslog.d/0-nut.conf`

But, when I do that, the filters stop logging to `/var/log/syslog`, and exclusively log to `/var/log/nut.log`... ?

Is there a different way to do this?

Thx!

Comment: Do you need the `& stop`? Do you have msgs with both "USB" and "nut-" that will get logged twice?

Comment: @meuh That was indeed my problem and your answer below was perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$IncludeConfig` or `include()` directive in `rsyslog.conf` appears before most of the standard rules, including the one that writes messages to `/var/log/syslog`. If you add your rules after the other rules in this file, then the nut messages will have already been written to `syslog` before it is also matched and written to `nut.log`.

If instead you put your rules in a separate file, the message will be written to `nut.log`, then the `stop` will skip the later rules.
The answer is not to use `stop`.

If the problem is that a message might contain both "USB" and "nut-", and so be written twice to `nut.log`, then you need to use a more sophisticated syntax.

The legacy syntax was replaced by [RainerScript](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/index.html) a long time ago.
It means you can write filters like:

```
if ($msg contains "USB" or $msg contains "nut-") then {
   action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/nut.log")
}
```

This does not need to prevent further processing of the message.

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot about the order of Rsyslog processing in your concise answer. I was indeed trying to avoid duplicated log msgs.